# How to make my loop to print only one value in java GUI?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, hash

So I have a for loop here:

```
String[] arr = new String[15];
answer = Integer.parseInt(keyTxt.getText());
        key = answer % 15;
        value = valueTxt.getText();

for(x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
                   if(arr[key] != null){
                       arr[key+1] = value;
                       listModel.addElement(x + " : " + arr[x]);
                   }
                   else if(arr[key] == null){
                       arr[key] = value;
                       listModel.addElement(x + " : " + arr[x]);
                   }

               }
```

This is the output that it print when I enter 118 in key and Love in values

```
0 : null
1 : null
2 : null
3 : null
4 : null
5 : null
6 : null
7 : null
8 : null
9 : null
10 : null
11 : null
12 : null
13 : Love
14 : Love
```

This is my desire output for it `13 : Love`

When I enter again **118 in key** and **new love** in values

```
0 : null
1 : null
2 : null
3 : null
4 : null
5 : null
6 : null
7 : null
8 : null
9 : null
10 : null
11 : null
12 : null
13 : Love
14 : New Love
```

here is my desired output for this:

```
13 : Love
14 : New Love
```

Someone help me please I am stuck with this for 2 days. Thank you :)

**EDIT**: This is hashing and we are not allowed to use the `HashTable` and `HashMap`only an array is allowed.

**This is what I did so far**

```
for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
         if(arr[key] != null){
         key++;
        }
         else if(arr[key] == null){
          key = key;
          }
         
          listModel.addElement(key + " : " + (arr[key] = value));
       }
```

**Note: ** This is not in terminal but in Java Gui

Comment: Simple input/output should be explained at every Java tutorial. Either adjust your loop or move the code which is responsible for your output outer your loop.

Comment: Where should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate logic for finding non empty spot and adding entries in listModel.
 Use `break;` statement to exit the loop when you've found the spot:

```
//put key in non empty spot
for (; key < arr.length; key++) {
    if (arr[key] == null) {
        arr[key] = value;
        break;
    }   
}

//add entries to display
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    listModel.add(i + " : " + arr[i] );
}
```

Demo code:

```
public class Test {
    public static List<String> listModel = new ArrayList<>();   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] arr = new String[15];
        
        int answer = 118;
        put(arr, answer, "Love");       
        //print
        listModel.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        
        System.out.println("\n Adding again -----------\n");
        put(arr, answer, "Love");       
        //print
        listModel.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        
    }
    static void put(String[] arr, int key, String value) {
        key = key % 15;
        while (key < arr.length) {
            if (arr[key] == null) {
                arr[key] = value;
                break;
            } else {
                key++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            listModel.add(i + " : " + arr[i] );
        }

    }
}
```

Note: I am using ArrayList instead of visual components for the demo.